# Does this fact about the minimal polynomial give an efficient diagonalizability criterion?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials, discriminant

In a very nice paper "When Is a Linear Operator Diagonalizable?" by Marco Abate ([Amer. Math. Monthly **104** (1997), 824-830](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975287)) I found the following nice description of the minimal polynomial $\mu(T)$ of an operator $T:V\to V$: for a vector $v\in V$ denote by $\mu_v(T)$, the *minimal polynomial of $T$ at $v$* as the smallest possible $a_0+a_1t+...+a_jt^j$ such that $a_0v+a_1T(v)+...+a_jT^j(v)=0$. Then $\mu(T)$ is the least common multiple of $\mu_{b_1}(T)$, ..., $\mu_{b_n}(T)$ for any basis $b_1$, ..., $b_n$ of $V$.

I wonder if this can be used to decide for diagonalizability of $T$ in an efficient way. More precisely, I mean this: we know that $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if the discriminant $\gcd(\mu(T),\mu'(T))$ is nonzero. Can we then utilize discriminants (or maybe some other combinations) of $\mu_{b_i}(T)$ for a basis of our choice, avoiding computation of $\mu(T)$ itself, to decide whether $T$ is diagonalizable?

In other words, is there an efficient way to compute the discriminant of a least common multiple of polynomials in terms of these polynomials, without computing the least common multiple itself?